# I want to show success message on form submission

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am stuck at a problem where I want to show a success message after the form is successfully submitted. I am using bootstrap and jQuery for that. I am also using an email service called [emailJS](https://emailjs.com) which allows us to send form data directly to our mail. Let me show you my code.

This is my code

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  var temp = {
    name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
    email: document.querySelector('#email').value,
    city: document.querySelector('#city').value,
    state: document.querySelector('#state').value
  };
  emailjs.send('service-register', 'register', temp)
    .then($('#messages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show())
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:submitForm()" id="register-form">
  <img src="img/logo.svg">
  <h2 class="title">Your Information</h2>
  <div class="input-div one">
    <div class="i">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
      <h5>Name</h5>
      <input id="name" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-div pass">
    <div class="i">
      <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
      <h5>E-mail</h5>
      <input id="email" type="email" class="input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-div pass">
    <div class="i">
      <i class="fas fa-city"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
      <h5>City</h5>
      <input id="city" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-div pass">
    <div class="i">
      <i class="fas fa-map-signs"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
      <h5>State</h5>
      <input id="state" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
  <div id="messages" class="hide">
    <button type="button" id="close" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> Thank you for getting in touch!
  </div>
</form>
```

It is sending the data correctly but not displaying the bootstrap alert. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Riddell Hi, Thanks for your time but I tried that and it's not working.

Comment: You should be using a submit event listener on the form so you can `preventDefault()` the browser submit process which causes navigation to occur

Comment: @VickyArora Apologies, I've moved the comment into a answer as it was too big for comment. If you've tried using function in the `.then` call and it's not working then I would suggest you need to make sure your jQuery code is working.

Comment: @Riddell Thanks for your answer. I am trying your solution. I will let you know if any problem persists.

Comment: @Riddell Hey, it is now showing "$ is not a function" this TypeError,

Comment: @VickyArora Can you confirm that jQuery is included in the HTML document? If you have you can change `$` to `jQuery` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states that `emailjs.send` returns a `Promise`.

You need to use anonymous or arrow function in the `.then` as it's expecting a function which is called when the promise is fulfilled. For example:

```js
 emailjs.send('service-register', 'register', temp)
        .then(function (response) {
            $('#messages')
             .removeClass('hide')
             .addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible')
             .slideDown()
             .show()
        });
```

If it's still not working then try and call your jQuery code after the email send call.

```js
 emailjs.send('service-register', 'register', temp);

 $('#messages')
  .removeClass('hide')
  .addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible')
  .slideDown()
  .show();
```

If the above does not work then you need to validate that your jQuery code is functioning as expected.

Instead of chaining then you can break it out into separate lines and step through each line in the debugger or start simple and just use `removeClass` and then `addClass` then build from that point.